# Multiple AND statements in QGIS Query Builder

Tags: qgis

In the QGIS Query Builder I am trying to filter by multiple fields. My filter expression is as follows:

`"VENTILTYPE" IN ('Skydeventil', 'Trykreduktionsventil') AND  "STATUS" = 'I brug'  AND "AABNINGSGRAD"='100'`

If I leave out one of the statements, everything works fine. 
The following two expressions works as they should:

```
"VENTILTYPE" IN ('Skydeventil', 'Trykreduktionsventil') AND  "STATUS" = 'I brug'
"VENTILTYPE" IN ('Skydeventil', 'Trykreduktionsventil') AND "AABNINGSGRAD"='100'
```

However as soon as I add an extra QGIS gives me the following error:

> 2019-07-31T16:13:28     CRITICAL    Layer Åben : Download of features for layer ugis:TL298 failed or partially failed: Download of features failed: Error transferring [Link for WFS] - server replied: Not Found. You may attempt reloading the layer with F5

What is causing this error?
Can the Query builder not handle 3 statements?

Comment: is there one or more features with both that STATUS and that AABINSGRAD?

Comment: It rather looks like a "web service" problem ... are your working with an WFS layer ? Does this error appear at any scale ? There are generally rules limiting the amount of objects downloaded by the WFS server ...

Comment: You can get the same effect by using a rule-based style with the same filter statement, instead of putting the filter in the query builder. Experiment with putting all of your filter into a rule-based style, or splitting the filter between the rule-based style and the query builder.

Comment: Yes there are features with those values.

I am working in a WFS layer. Yes it appears at any scale.

The filter statements works well in the rule-based style, and it actually suits my needs better. Thank you very much for your help!